# change filter expression with abutton click

Tags: vb.net

I want to change my filter expression if a certain item is selected in a dropdownlist and the person clicks the button

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "JOANNEP" Or DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "ANAB" Then
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "byyyy <> 2009"
        Else
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = Nothing
        End If
        UpdatePanel1.Update()
    End Sub
```

i tryed that however my gridview still shows byyyy years that include 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling  `gridView1.DataBind()` after the `If-Else-EndIf` block;

EDIT: Just guessing but try this

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "byyyy <> {0}"
SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("byyyy", "2009")
```

Comment: still nothing, its wierd it works when i put the filter directly in the sqldatasource : /

Comment: still nothing : / this should be simple

Comment: ok so i think the problem lies in the fact that its not reading the dropdownlist names correctly because if i do what u said in my else statement it works

Comment: @bugz try setting a breakpoint and see what the dropdown's SelectedItem.Text actually is.

Comment: i just kept it as index for now  which stinks because it will break if i add a new employee : (